# Does the Hessian matrix of energy function of a gradient system have to be positive semidefinite when the system has one globally stable point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, hessian-matrix, gradient-flows

Given a gradient dynamical system
$$\frac{d\theta_i}{dt}=f_i(\theta_1,\cdots,\theta_n),\forall i\in\{1,\cdots,n\},$$
where
$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial \theta_i}=f_i(\theta_1,\cdots,\theta_n),$$

where $G$ is the energy function.

Assume now that there exists a globally asymptotic stable equilibrium point. Does the Hessian matrix of the $G$ have to be positive semidefinite ($G$ is convex function)?

**Remark**

I basically curious that:

On the one hand, if we know there exists a globally asymptotic stable equilibrium point, whether we would have some properties on $G$.

On the other hand, what conditions on $G$ could deduce the globally asymptotic stability of an equilibrium point.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You are talking about the Hessian of $G$, correct?

Comment: @KBS Yes, the Hessian of G.

Comment: Is $G$ convex an assumption or something that needs to be proven? It is not clear.

Comment: @KBS It is something I am not sure whether it is correct. I basically curious that if we know there exists a globally asymptotic stable equilibrium point, whether we would have some properties on $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ being an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $G:U\to \mathbb{R}$ a two times continuously differentiable function.

If $x(t)$ is a solution to the differential equation $$\begin{cases}
\displaystyle \frac{dx}{dt}&=&\nabla G(x)\\x(0)&=&x_0\end{cases}\tag{1}$$ then  $$\frac{dG(x(t))}{dt}=\nabla G(x(t))\cdot \nabla G(x(t))=\|\nabla G(x(t))\|^2\geq 0,\tag{2}$$ $x(t)$ follows the [steepest ascent direction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/223252/why-is-gradient-the-direction-of-steepest-ascent?msclkid=6dbf96f4d15811ec97a031cd2d996992), and $G(x(t))$ is non decreasing.

If we assume that there exists a globally asymptotic stable equilibrium point $x^*$ to $(1)$. Then $x(t)\to x^*$, to any $x_0$, as $t\to +\infty$, and $$\max_xG(x)=G(x^*).\tag{3}$$

This, in particular, means that Hessian matrix $HG(x^*)$ [has no positive eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_theory?msclkid=5f276d7ad15c11ecb930e45a5d2ac4f9#Non-linear_autonomous_systems). As so, it is not positive semidefinite.

You can find some related discussions searching for "[\(\dot{x}=\nabla G(x)\)](https://www.searchonmath.com/result/?q=%5C%28%5Cdot%7Bx%7D%3D%5Cnabla%20G%28x%29%5C%29%20)" on SearchOnMath, for instance.

**Note:**

1. What happens if you choose [$G(x)=e^{-\|x\|^2}$?](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28e%5E%28-%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%29%29%2C+-10%3Cx%3C10%2C-10%3Cy%3C10).
2. Now, if we assume that there is a unique global maximum $x^*$ for $(3)$. Then this point is an equilibrium point for $(1)$, and $x(t)\to x^*$, as $t\to +\infty$, for any $x_0$ close enough to $x^ *$ . If there is some $x_0\in U$ and some $r>0$, such that $\|x(t)-x^*\|\geq r$, as $t\to +\infty$, then $( 2)-(3)$ implies that $G(x(t))\to M$, for some $M<G(x^*)$. Therefore, if $x(t)$ is bounded, then $M$ is a local maximum, and $x(t)$ approximates some non-empty set $Y^*\subset{R}^n$ containing equilibrium points of $(1)$.
3. Therefore, if we assume that there is a unique global maximum $x^*$ for $(3)$ and there is no other local maximum, then any bounded solution $x(t)$ to $(1)$, is such that $x(t)\to x^*$, as $t\to +\infty$, when $x_0$ is not a local minimum or saddle point.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I am bit confused about the statement, why is that: If we assume that there exists a globally asymptotic stable equilibrium point $x^*$ to (1). Then ()→∗, to any 0 as →∞, and $max_x(x)=(x^∗)$

Comment: Since I think if $G(x)$ is concave, then we have $x^*$ is globally asymptotically stable. But inverse, I don't think it must hold.

Comment: Do you agreed that $x(t)$ follows the steepest ascent direction? If so, $x(t)$ goes to the maximum direction. The globally asymptotic stable equilibrium point definition tell us that no matter where $x_0$ is, $x(t)\to x^*$.

Comment: Please see [Global stability vs Global asymptotic stability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3789696/global-stability-vs-global-asymptotic-stability).

Comment: I misunderstood. what I was trying to say it that to guarantee $x^*$ is globally asymptotically stable, it is not necessary for $G(x)$ to be globally convex function.

Comment: I agree that if $x^*$ is globally asymptotic stable (GAS), then $x*$ is the global maximum of $G(x)$. Inversely, if $G(x)$ is global maximum on $x^*$, we cannot conclude that $x^*$ is GAS, right? Then, what additional condition is needed to conclude it? My attempt is  that, we need $G(x)$ is globally convex. Thanks! 
P.s. thanks for the link of search on math, I don't know there exists such useful tool before.

Comment: @HJ_dynamics I include some notes.